# Displaying splash screen while setContentView runs

Tags: android

I am currently trying to reduce the cold start time of my app, and I have hit the point where the majority of the time is spent in setContentView (~2 secs out of 2.6 secs).

I want to reduce this further, and one approach I am thinking of is displaying a splash screen while setContentView does its job. However, this seems almost counterintuitive, because (I think) setContentView operates on the UI thread, so wouldn't displaying a splash screen clash with setContentView?

Additionally, I am confused on why my setContentView is taking so long considering my XML. If the load time of setContentView could be directly addressed, that is certainly another option.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- The main content view -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_content">
        </FrameLayout>

        <!-- The navigation drawer -->
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/selector_dark_text"
            android:background="@drawable/dark_background"
            app:itemBackground="@drawable/selector_dark"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/selector_dark_text"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "I have hit the point where the majority of the time is spent in setContentView (~2 secs out of 2.6 secs)" -- how exactly have you determined this? When you used Android Studio's method tracing, what did it show? In terms of the splash screen, you can use a graphic in your theme: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Comment: I tracked it in the Flame Chart in the CPU Profiler. It seems quite inconsistent however, but seems to always be at minimum 1 second (which I consider is still quite substantial). The issue with the article you linked is that the splash screen is simply to account for the natural delay when opening an app, while I am trying to use the splash screen to account for in my setContentView delay.

Comment: I'd be highly doubtful that setContentView actually takes 2 seconds.  I'd measure using LayoutInflater to inflate it and compare.  I've loaded far more complex UI in far less time.  Its far more likely your problem is either elsewhere in onCreate, or in your measurement/layout of views